# Capybara FactoryGirl Carrierwave cannot attach file

Tags: cucumber, capybara, carrierwave, factory-bot

I am trying to test my application with cucumber and capybara.
I have the following step definition:

```
Given(/^I fill in the create article form with the valid article data$/) do
  @article_attributes = FactoryGirl.build(:article)
  within("#new_article") do
    fill_in('article_title', with: @article_attributes.title)
    attach_file('article_image', @article_attributes.image)
    fill_in('article_description', with: @article_attributes.description)
    fill_in('article_key_words', with: @article_attributes.key_words)
    fill_in('article_body', with: @article_attributes.body)
  end
```

My article factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    sequence(:title) {|n| "Title #{n}"}
    description 'Description'
    key_words 'Key word'
    image { File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/support/example.jpg')) }
    body 'Lorem...'
    association :admin, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

And this is my uploader file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class ArticleImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

But each time i run this scenario i get ERROR message:

```
Given I fill in the create article form with the valid article data # features/step_definitions/blog_owner_creating_article.rb:1
      cannot attach file, /uploads/article/image/1/example.jpg does not exist (Capybara::FileNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/blog_owner_creating_article.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/blog_owner_creating_article.rb:3:in `/^I fill in the create article form with the valid article data$/'
      features/blog_owner_creating_article.feature:13:in `Given I fill in the create article form with the valid article data'
```

I also found that FactoryGirl returns `image:nil` when i run `FactoryGirl.build(:article)` in my rails test console.

Could anybody explain me what i am doing wrong,please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the path in directly:

```
attach_file('article_image', File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/support/example.jpg'))
```

What's happening here is that `attach_file` expects a string, not a CarrierWave uploader. When you pass it an uploader (`@article_attributes.image`), `attach_file` is calling `Uploader#to_s`, which calls `Uploader#path`. Since you haven't saved the article yet, the path at which the uploaded image will be located is invalid.

Note also that calling your variable `@article_attributes` is confusing, since it's actually a full article object, not just a hash. If that's what you want, you may want to try `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article)`.

Comment: Thaks for answering! I'd tried to use `@article_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article)` as you said. But  `@article_attributes[:image]` returns `#<File:/home/olebi/Work/blog_engine/spec/support/example.jpg>`. Is there any way to transform this into the direct string path?`

Comment: `@article_attributes[:image].path`? It'd be a crazy world if there was no way [to get the path from a File object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-i-path).

Comment: Just a little caveat, because it took me some time to figure out why my tests were failing: If your factory populates the upload with `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`, the path might not be what you expect. `UploadedFile` adds some kind of fingerprint to the filename, so 'dummy.jpg' becomes e. g. 'dummy.jpg20140221-25167-11iad2p' (probably because it stores all the files in /tmp). This might trip your extension white list and fail your tests. If this happens, it might be a better solution to call `attach_file` with the file path itself instead of the attribute that FactoryGirl produces.